# Add AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly managed policy to role using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to add the managed policy **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly** to a beanstalk created role **aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role**

According to the documentation this should be the right way

```
EXAMPLES
       To attach a managed policy to an IAM role

       The  following attach-role-policy command attaches the AWS managed pol-
       icy named ReadOnlyAccess to the IAM role named ReadOnlyRole:

          aws iam attach-role-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess --role-name ReadOnlyRole
```

**Attempt:**

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly --role-name aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
```

**Problem:**

I get a black terminal screen, no output and a (END) written.

**Question:**

What do I have to do to add that managed policy **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly** to the default **aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role** Role

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the way shown above. I just made a mistake listing the policies via api, so I could not see it. Maybe the above instruction is helpful to anyone.